# Generating Factorial Integral

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{at-e^t}\,dt=a!$ if $a \geq 1$.

How do I even go about proving this???

All I was able to do was confirm this for $a$ = $1,2,3...10$.

Comment: You'll want to prove this with induction on $a$.  Start with $a = 0$, and then prove that if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{at-t^2}dt = a!$, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(a+1)t-t^2}dt = (a+1)!$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your (improper) integral is not equal to $a!$.

By completing the square for the term in the exponent one can write
$$at - t^2 = \frac{a^2}{4} - \left (t - \frac{a}{2} \right )^2.$$
So your integral becomes
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{at - t^2} \, dt = e^{\frac{a^2}{4}} \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-(t - a/2)^2} \, dt.$$
After making the substitution $t \mapsto t - \frac{a}{2}$ one has
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{at - t^2} \, dt = e^{\frac{a^2}{4}} \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-t^2} \, dt.$$
The result for this last integral is well known. It is the Gaussian (or probability) integral and is equal to $\sqrt{\pi}$. Thus
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{at - t^2} \, dt = e^{\frac{a^2}{4}} \sqrt{\pi},$$ and is valid for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.